# Python string replace ""

Tags: python, string

I want to replace "" with ", as it screws with the json decoder

```
val = '''""what""'''
print(val) # ""what""
val.replace('""', '"')
print(val) # ""what""
```

Input ""what"" 
Desired output "what" 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace each double quote with a single quote (that is, replace `"what"` with `'what'`)?

Comment: Edited for clarification, ""what"" is input, "what" is desired output

Comment: `val.replace('""', '"')` builds a new string you do nothing with. You probably want `val = val.replace('""', '"')`.